# Why is LINQ OrderByDescending not working with a view composed of a union between two tables?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, devforce

I have a view in my SQL Server database that is a UNION ALL of two tables. When I retrieve all the rows from the view for a specific member, this is my call.

```
 public IEnumerable<MemberTransaction> GetMemberTransactions(string socSecNo)
 {
     var query = Manager.MemberTransactions
         .Where(m => m.SocSecNo == socSecNo)
        .OrderByDescending(m => m.TranDate);

     var results = query.Execute();

     return results;
 }
```

I call the Get method from my code and assign the returned collection to the datasource propery of a grid. The rows are not displayed as per the order by statement in the Get method. they are displayed in random order.

I am forced to do this to get the rows to display properly.

```
    IEnumerable<MemberTransaction> transactions = FetchMemberTransactions(currentMember.SocSecNo);
    MemberTransactionBS.DataSource = transactions.OrderByDescending(t => t.TranDate);
    MemberTransactionsGrid.Refresh();

    public IEnumerable<MemberTransaction> FetchMemberTransactions(string socSecNo)
    {
         var transactions = Repository.GetMemberTransactions(socSecNo);
         return transactions;
    }
```

Is there an issue with returning rows from a union? Why is the `OrderByDescending` not working as expected?

Comment: Is `transactions` ordered as you expected?

Comment: As Carth suggests the first step is in working out where exactly the failure in ordering is. Does it come back from your database in the wrong order (test by breakpoint in `GetMemberTransactions` and looking at your data) or somewhere else? The code you've presented really shouldn't need that extra order by so I'm assuming that this is a cut down version of the code? Do you definitely have no other operations acting on your results between the `query.Execute()` and your final use of it? Bear in mind that I suspect many linq operations make no guarantee of maintaining ordering (I may be wrong).

Comment: I check the rows coming back in GetMemberTransactions and they are not ordered. I have no other code. I cannot get the data in the grid to be sorted without that extra orderby statement.

Answer (score 0):

If the order is being returned correctly from the database (test this first like other answers sugest) try returning an  `IOrderedEnumerable<MemberTransaction>` instead of `IEnumerable<MemberTransaction>`.

Comment: I used IOrderedEnumerable to hold the collection returned and the data is still not in the correct ordered by sequence.

Comment: Then try firing up Sql Server Profiler and check the query that's being generated by your code and see if it is correct.

Comment: ok i did that and here is the sql statement sent to the database

Comment: sorry it wont let me display it as it is too long but an order by descending on the trandate is being sent

Answer (score -1):

You said First Way doesn't work but it worked on me! So try Second Way please.

```
    // First Way
    public List<MemberTransaction> GetMemberTransactions(string socSecNo)
    {
        var orderedListOfData = Manager.MemberTransactions
                                .Where(m => m.SocSecNo == socSecNo)
                                .OrderByDescending(m => m.TranDate).ToList();
        return orderedListOfData;
    }



     // Second Way
     public List<MemberTransaction> GetMemberTransactions(string socSecNo)
     {
         var orderedListOfData = (from m in Manager.MemberTransactions
                                  where m.SocSecNo == socSecNo
                                  orderby m.TranDate descending
                                  select m).ToList();
         return orderedListOfData;
      }
```

Comment: I just tried this and the rows still are not be returned in the orderbydescending order.

Comment: Boss, if you have data in your db, its impossible to not return somethings:) What about when you debug your code line by line and when your debugger comes over the "query" line? Didn't it return anything?

Comment: yes it returns the correct number of rows for that member, in this case 576 rows. But as i said the rows are not ordered according to the orderby clause they are ordered randomly.

Comment: Aha! So there must be a problem with your "TranDate"! Excuse me to ask this stupid question but are you exactly sure that you have your TranDate datas descending properly? If so, lemme have its format?

Comment: If the run a query in sql server using the order by trandate desc the output displayed is in the correct order. So the sql statement that makes up the view and the union is correct. The problem is that linq cannot properly order a union view.

Comment: Menh, so try Second Way, Actually both of them worked on me. So you try the other one. It definetally works too!

Comment: i have tried both. they both return the correct number of rows but they don't return the rows in the orderbydescending order. they are in random order

Comment: so i'm %100 sure there is a problem with your TranDate format!! Check it out well that colon has properly desceding datas..